# How do I sum 1/6( e^t + e^2t + .... + e^6t)?

Tags: summation, actuarial-science, exponential-sum

I have a question about a sum when calculating moment generating function. 
The question is : "Find the moment generating function for each of these two random variables. (i) $X$ = outcome a die toss, $p(x) = P[X= x] = \frac{1}{6}$ for $x = 1,2,3,4,5,6$. I don't understand how the sum in the answer $e^t \cdot \frac{1}{6} + e^{2t} \cdot \frac{1}{6} +...+ e^{6t}\cdot \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{6}e^t\frac{e^{6t}-1}{e^t-1}$. 
Why doesn't it work to have this as the sum of a finite geometric series with the common ratio being $e^t$?

Comment: The standard geometric series goes like $1+x+\cdots$. You have something like $x+x^2+\cdots=x(1+x+\cdots)$.

Comment: thank you! I see, so I need to factor out $e^t$. Also I think I just got confused because in the end you can factor out -1 of the final fraction from $\frac{1-e^{6t}}{1-e^t}$, I think.

Answer (score -1):

I think it doesn't work with finite geometric series because $e$ is not rational number, but I am not sure

Comment: There's nothing that says the common ratio must be rational.

Comment: The finite sum expression works for any $r\neq 1$.

Comment: Thank you for info